# Schlecht helfen

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Heute gab es einen Streit vor mir. Eine Kundin wollte ihr Handy reparieren lassen. Der Geschäftsbesitzer versuchte, ihr Handy zu reparieren, konnte er aber nicht. Als die Kundin sah, dass er es nicht schaffen wird, hat sie gesagt, dass sie woanders hingehen wird, um ihr Handy reparieren zu lassen. Er war selbstverständlich beleidigt und hat ihr deswegen die Tür gezeigt.

Während sie gegangen ist, hat sie ihm gesagt:

> Sie haben mir schlecht geholfen.

Ich finde diesen Satz sinnlos und konnte nicht begreifen, was sie gemeint hat.

*Schlecht helfen* kann bedeuten, dass er ihr geholfen hat. Aber da sie mehr Hilfe von ihm erwartet hat, war sie wegen der Bedienung unzufrieden.

*Schlecht helfen* kann auch bedeuten, dass er mehr geschadet hat, als er geholfen hat.

Was hat sie eigentlich gemeint?

Comment: Vermutlich eine Mischung aus "Sie haben mir nicht geholfen" und "Sie haben mich schlecht bedient" o.ä.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was sie (sehr wahrscheinlich) gemeint hat, ist die erste Auslegung:

> Schlecht helfen kann bedeuten, dass er ihr geholfen hat aber da sie mehr Hilfe von ihm erwartet hat, war sie deswegen von der Bedienung unzufrieden.

Ich würde es evtl. so formulieren:

> "Was Sie getan haben, war nicht besonders hilfreich"

[ **Anmerkung:**

Die zweite Auslegung ist mir so, mit in dieser Formulierung, noch nicht nie untergekommen:

> Schlecht helfen kann auch bedeuten, dass er mehr geschadet hat, als er geholfen hat.

Man könnte die Bedeutung so formulieren:

> "Sie haben mir durch helfen Schlechtes angetan"

Das würde man aber nicht in dieser Weise "abkürzen".]

Comment: "Was Sie getan haben, war nicht besonders hilfreich". Du hast recht, diese Bedeutung ist am logischsten aber warum sagt man nicht einfach: Sie haben mir nicht geholfen. Du hast mir nicht geholfen vs Du hast mir schlecht geholfen. Welcher Satz ist beleidigender? Ich versuche den Effekt von Schlecht in diesem Kontext zu verstehen.

Comment: Ich persönlich habe die Erfahrung gemacht, das Leute - gerade in solchen Situationen - nicht immer das sagen, was grammatikalisch richtig wäre.
Sprach-Qualitativ ist die Aussage "Sie haben mir schlecht geholfen" eher schlecht einzustufen. Daher würde ich dir recht geben, sie hätte es anders - und besser - formulieren können.

Comment: Edit - Ich habe jetzt erst den ganzen Kommentar gelesen... "Sie haben mir schlecht geholfen" klingt tatsächlich beleidigender, gerade wegen dem Kontrast (helfen vs. schlecht)

Comment: Der Kontrast in dem Satz hat auch dann eine Bedeutung :) Danke sehr für deine Antwort.

Comment: Ich fürchte, da ist weniger dran als du denkst. Natürlich klingt der eine Satz um direkten Vergleich ein bisschen beleidigender. Ich denke aber nicht, dass sich die Dame in der Situation genau das gedacht hat. Wahrscheinlich war es in der Aufregung eher eine Vermischung der beiden Sätze "Sie haben mich schlecht bedient" und "Sie haben mir nicht nicht/wenig geholfen." (siehe dirkts Kommentar)

Comment: Es ist zwar grammatikalisch richtig, aber sprachlich absolut unüblich, "Hilfe" und "schlecht" oder allgemein "Hilfe" und ein negatives Wort zu kombinieren. Typische Adjektive sind "schnell" oder "professionell".

Answer (score 4):

Da müsste man die Kundin selbst fragen. Wir können nur raten. Aber beide Möglichkeiten, die du genannt hast, sind plausibel.

Der folgende Satz ist klar:

> Sie haben mir geholfen.

Der Satz sagt aus, dass der Sprecher von der Person, mit der er spricht, Hilfe erhalten hat.

Zum Vergleich:

> Sie haben mir schlecht geholfen.

Dieser Satz transportiert dieselbe Aussage (der Sprecher hat vom Adressaten Hilfe erhalten), macht aber zusätzlich noch eine Angabe zur Qualität der Hilfe. Das adverbiell verwendete Adjektiv »schlecht« gibt an, dass die Hilfe von minderer Qualität war.

Mehr kann man - ohne weiter Kenntnis des Kontext - aus diesem Satz nicht herauslesen.

Comment: Ja, auf jeden Fall war sie von der Situation und der Qualität der Bedienung unzufrieden. Ist es irgendwie höflichere Version von "Du hast mir nicht geholfen".

Comment: Ich meine, was würdest du verstehen, falls ich Dir sagen würde: Deine Antwort hat mir schlecht geholfen. Irgendwie passt "was Negatives: schlecht" zu "was Positives: helfen" nicht ganz.

Comment: Ich würde mir denken, dass die Dame in der Aufregung einfach nicht schnell genug die richtigen Worte gefunden hat, und einfach das gesagt hat, was ihr Hirn in der Schnelle gerade hergegeben hat.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Deine Antwort. Man soll dann nicht alles, was man hört, tief denken:)